# Where to find Geman 1995's proof on Changes of Numaraire?

Tags: measure-theory, finance

Geman, H., El Karoui, N., Rochet, J.C. (1995) published paper "Changes of Numeraire, Changes of Probability Measures and Pricing of Options", on "Journal of Applied Probability
" vol 32, pg 443-458.

This is a proof on the basic Numeraire changing methods in Financial Engineering.

May I check where could I find a copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a copy of the article [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3215299?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103842820787).